# /bin/ 以下の削除後、Ubuntu の端末が起動しなくなりました (Could not exec /bin/sh そのようなファイルやディレクトリはありません)

Tags: ubuntu, bash, 端末, dash

環境構築していた際、間違って `/bin/` 以下を強制削除してしまい、仕方なくインストール済のバージョンと同じcoreutilsを取得し、binフォルダ以下を `/bin/` にコピーしました。

ここまでは端末は起動していたのですが、以降端末を起動しようとしても起動せず、xtermを選択しても、「Could not exec /bin/sh そのようなファイルやディレクトリはありません」と表示され、起動しなくなってしまいました。

環境構築はUbuntu 18.04で実施しており、関連する操作として `/bin` を削除する前に、以下を実施しておりました。

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure dash     [no を選択]
$ sudo rm /bin/sh
$ sudo ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh
```

勉強不足で大変恐縮ではございますが、解決方法または参考サイトをご教示いただけないでしょうか？

Comment: 原因もわかっていることですし、再インストールすればいいのでは？

Comment: 再インストールせずに解決する手段を探しております。

Comment: `ls -lL /bin/sh` の結果はどうなりますか？

Comment: /home をキープして再インストールするのも一つの手だとは思いますが。

Answer (score 0):

[Ubuntuパッケージの内容](https://packages.ubuntu.com/) 調べると, 以下のような結果です

- (Ubuntu/Debian において) 通常のシェルスクリプト用 … [dash](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=dash&mode=exactfilename&suite=groovy&arch=any)
- ターミナルなどでよく使われるシェル … [bash](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=bash&mode=exactfilename&suite=groovy&arch=any)

`coreutils` にはある程度の `/bin/`以下のコマンドは含まれていますが, `bash`動かすのなら `bash`パッケージが必要です。(ほかのシェルならそれ用のパッケージ)
それを取得し, (`coreutils`のように) `/bin/` 以下に展開することになるでしょう

Comment: 結果として,/bin/shはなし。bash, dash等を取得し回復させたかったのですが、再起動で復帰しなくなり、結局再インストールいたしました。

Answer (score 0):

未検証ですが、"ubuntu repair" 等で検索してみると以下のような手順が見つかりました。

[How To Fix Broken Ubuntu OS Without Reinstalling It](https://ostechnix.com/how-to-fix-broken-ubuntu-os-without-reinstalling-it/)

```
$ sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
$ sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
$ sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
$ sudo apt clean
$ sudo apt update --fix-missing
$ sudo apt install -f
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
$ sudo apt upgrade
$ sudo apt dist-upgrade
$ sudo reboot
```